# RealmJS: Correct query to fetch object from list with AND consition

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-js

Schema of Product has many details like: productName, manufactured date,  manufacturer name, product type etc. But I need to support flexibility of having no defined schema for product details. To achieve this below is the Realm-JS schema.

```
import Realm from 'realm';
export default class ProductModel extends Realm.Object { }
    ProductModel.schema = {
        name: 'ProductModel',
        properties: {
            productAttributes: { type: 'list', objectType: 'ProductDetailsModel' },
            ID: { type: 'string', optional: true },        
        }
    };
```

---

```
import Realm from 'realm';
export default class ProductDetailsModel extends Realm.Object { }
ProductDetailsModel.schema = {
    name: 'ProductDetailsModel',
    properties: {
        attributeName: { type: 'string', optional: true },
        attributeValue: { type: 'string', optional: true },
    }
};
```

This flexibility is yielding in complexity of writing filter query. I need to be able to filter based on particular Product attribute name and Product Attribute values.

```
let query = "productAttributes.attributeName = " + "\"" + "Manufacturer" + "\"" + " AND productAttributes.attributeValue = [c]" + "\"" + "Pepsico" + "\"";        

        var productList = this.realm.objects('ProductModel').filtered(query).snapshot();
```

Please help me to **write query to filter the ProductModel from DB matching ProductDetailsModel both attributeName and  attributeValue ?**

Current query does not match single ProductDetailsModel where attributeName ="Manufacturer" AND attributeValue = "Pepsico"

Answer (score 0):

You reference it by the Objects local attribute, not the name of the linked object. e.g.

```
let attributeName = "Manufacturer"
let attributeValue = "Pepsico"
let query = `productAttributes.attributeName  ==[c] '${attributeName}' AND productAttributes.attributeValue ==[c] '${attributeValue}'`
```

Comment: My bad, i did a typo in question, now corrected it. But result is same.

Comment: The syntax is ok. is it a fully or partially synced realm? Can you fetch the models without the filtered?

Comment: I wanted to high level ProductModel object which matches attributeName and attributeValue together. With the current query it returns ProductModel when at least  one attributeName = "Manufacturer" and at least  one attributeValue = "Pepsico" . How can I express it should match  attributeValue if and only if it matches attributeName. Hope I am clear.